# Is there reference documentation for CloudInit?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, documentation

Ubuntu's CloudInit package is very useful; however, the only documentation I've found on all of the available options is in their examples: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/view/head:/doc/examples/cloud-config.txt

Numerous Google searches have failed me. Where can I find thorough documentation on CloudInit?

Comment: Agreed. I'm using cloud-init, but only as minimally as possible, due to lack of good documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I've just looked in the package for 12.04LTS (0.6.3-0ubuntu1) I can see there's some documentation available in a few text files in /usr/share/doc/cloud-init alongside the examples which may help

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit is another source of information.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime documentation has been placed here:
http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/