# Different behavior of ubuntu-cloud image between LXC and libvirt-lxc

Tags: ubuntu, libvirt, lxc

I've used ubuntu-cloud template as LXC containers, and they all worked fine. Recently I switched to use `libvirt-lxc`, and followed instructions in [Ubuntu document](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-libvirt), but the image initialized differently from LXC:

1. Tried to connect to AWS's meta-data server and got errors:

   ```
   2013-02-05 00:55:48,209 - util.py[WARNING]: 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [50/120s]: url error [timed out]
   ```
2. Default password didn't work. I need to enable password by modifying the rootfs' `/etc/shadow` because the default password of "ubuntu" account had been banned.

I think LXC pre-handle the `cloud-init` issues and feed it some user-data and meta-data. I tried to find how to do this manually, but the `cloud-init` document page didn't help, [because it's examples are all for `euca-tools`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit).

And I also noticed that `lxc-start` has an option `-C` :*"The -C option will create a cloud container, configured for use with a metadata service."* But I just didn't know how to map this option and it's all related settings to `libvirt_lxc`.

How can I init the image/rootfs correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after searching several days to solve the `cloud-init` issues, I found I can prepare a `seed` disk to mount in guest system to let `cloud-init` boot with. In detail:

1. [Create a `libvirt` domain XML with LXC rootfs](http://libvirt.org/drvlxc.html)
2. Prepare `meta-data` and `user-data` files just following [this reference](http://qa.ubuntu.com/2012/06/19/local-ubuntu-vm-provisioning-with-cloud-init/)
3. Instead of createing a ISO file, we can add a mount option in our domain XML to seed files to `cloud-init`:

   ```
   <!-- language: lang-xml -->
   <filesystem type='mount'>
     <source dir='./seed-dir-path'/>

     <!-- Make sure your rootfs has `/var/lib/cloud/seed` directory first-->

     <target dir='/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud'/>
   </filesystem>
   ```
4. Define the domain and start it. Now the `cloud-init` will get the `meta-data` and `user-data`.

And, `cloud-init` lacks documents [[1](http://libvirt.org/drvlxc.html)](https://serverfault.com/questions/430457/is-there-reference-documentation-for-cloudinit),[[2](http://qa.ubuntu.com/2012/06/19/local-ubuntu-vm-provisioning-with-cloud-init/)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit). I've spent a lots of time on searching pieces of information from issue tracker, blog and even github repos. In contrast, the `libvirt`, has a useful Wiki at least.